# Is it possible to combine IP-based and IAM-based access control policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-control, amazon-iam

I have an AWS ElasticSearch cluster to which I want to restrict access.

Ideally I want to use both IAM access (to allow our other service components to contact the cluster) and IP-based access (to allow ad-hoc testing via Sense from within our local network), but when I just tried to add both options to the access control policy it didn't allow access from the listed IP addresses.

Is it possible to combine the two policy styles like this? I assumed from `"Statement": []` in the autogenerated JSON that it would be.

An anonymised MWE:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "PLACEHOLDER",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "PLACEHOLDER",
            "PLACEHOLDER",
            "PLACEHOLDER"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "PLACEHOLDER"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "PLACEHOLDER"
    }
  ]
}
```

The IpAddress section had previously worked, but I have no easy way to test if the IAM section worked as we lost access to ad hoc testing when trying it (as expected - the ad hoc testing is not from inside the AWS account).